# Testing an android app on real device without USB

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, onesignal

I have made an app in Android studio with a button, which sends notification with OneSignal API when it's clicked and I have a question about the app. First of all, my app is working fine when I connect my real phone via usb and the button is working perfectly. However, I want to use the app from my phone without a connection via usb and also, I want to send my app to one of my friends to test it. I tried to build the app and I sent it to my phone but it didn't work. I hope you can help me with this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to post some more information, like what happens when you try to install. From what you've posted everything your doing sounds normal except it doesn't work and thats not enough info to go on.

Comment: go to Build -> Builds Bundle -> Build Apks  after that apk will be build send that build with your friend

Comment: debugging without usb cable? Try using Wifi ADB tool plugin in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your Android APP without a USB cable I think you can debug it using the same wifi, if you want your friend to try it in his/her mobile phone go to Build->Generate APK (don't click "generate signed APK"). this way your friend can install this app in his mobile phone and can test it.

if this isn't helping provide us more information.

Comment: Well, I want to try the app in one of my friend's mobile phone without having the same wifi. That is, I want to share my app to other phones. I built the app like you said and I sent it via email to my friend's phone. I see that notification is sent but it isn't appearing on his phone. Can we help me with this problem?